# Is there a way to make the Foundation Accordion work Horizontaly?

Tags: zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

I'm searching for a way to make the Foundation accordion work Horizontally, like zAccordion http://www.armagost.com/zaccordion/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was asked on the Foundation forum and http://codepen.io/rafibomb/pen/ByEPJP was provided as an answer. You can see the full thread with examples here: http://foundation.zurb.com/forum/posts/23829-horizontal-accordion

They added a class of `accordion` to the row and adjusted the SCSS this way:

```
.row.accordion {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  transform-origin: 35%;
  .content {
    min-height: 450px;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
  }
}
```